# Loop to fill an array for use in listview (fill array from txt file strings)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to fill an array for use in a listview in android.  I want the array to be filled with data stored in several .txt files on the sdcard.  I have an Int names Mx that tells the loop how many times to run (well thats what i would like it to do).  The value Mx is also the number of entries required in the array.

I am currently using this code but it doesnt work:

```
 public void arrayload() {
        ///////////////////////////////////working here///////////////////////////////// 
         //new looping code
         for (int i=1; i<=Mx; i++){
                try{
                     String fileName = String.valueOf(i) +".txt";   
                     File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mx/" +fileName);
                     FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(fIn));
                        String aDataRow = "";
                        String aBuffer = "";
                        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
                        }
                String[] lvdata = new String[Mx];
                lvdata[i] = aBuffer;
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.logbooklayout, lvdata);
                   lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
                   lv1.scrollTo(0, mxlv); // set the listview at a sensible point
                }
                 catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
         }
```

I have previously been hardcoding each entry into the array but am trying to tidy the code up so it loops based on the value Mx.  I know the array and listview work fine if i manually fill them, wheni use the code below the app crashes.

Logcat output is

```
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:645)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:425)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-02 16:41:23.888: E/AndroidRuntime(31497):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help with this is really welcome.  I am just cutting my teeth with Java so my code is in need of improving lots!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this !

```
public void arrayload() {
        ///////////////////////////////////working here///////////////////////////////// 

     String[] lvdata = new String[Mx];

     for (int i=0 ; i < Mx ;i++){
        lvdata[i]="";
     }

         for (int i=0; i<Mx; i++){
                try{
                     String fileName = String.valueOf(i) +".txt";   
                     File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mx/" +fileName);
                     FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(fIn));
                        String aDataRow = "";
                        String aBuffer = "";
                        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
                        }

                lvdata[i] = aBuffer;

                }
                 catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
     }  
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.logbooklayout, lvdata);
    lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv1.scrollTo(0, mxlv); // set the listview at a sensible point
}
```

There are two problems in your code :

- First you instanatiate the array you fill at each loop. So imagine Mx=3 i =2,as you just put a value in lvDate[2] , lvdata[0] and lvdata[1] are null hence NullpointerException.
- Second you instantiate adapter each loop too.

Try using Logcat and not Toast "Log.e(tag, msg, tr)" you can pass your exception directly.

Hope it'll help

Comment: Thanks for this.  Well in some ways I can be happy i wasnt that far off, but yes now you have given me the explanation it seems obvious i was looping everything!  Thank you, just to ask on the logcat point, if i put Log.e(tag, msg, tr) will that cut down the amount of logcat im having to work through when i do code a crash?

Comment: I still get a force close when trying to fill the array using the way you described.  The logcat output looks very similar... any thoughts?

Comment: You can have also another problem. if you got an exception while you are getting data you may have a null item in your array. To confirm this try to init every value of your array before the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  How to you mean I should Init every value in the array? Values <=Mx all have data in the txt files and they are all there available for the app to read, but is that not what you mean?

Comment: I mean a problem may occur during reading. So to confrim or infirm this hypothesis. you should init lvdata before the  loop. It will definitively not solve your problem but tou 'll have more info. I edit the post to show you.

Comment: thanks, I will give this a try tomorrow. thanks for all your help

Comment: tried init the array as you described but I'm still getting a force close each time this loop runs. is there anything else that I can try? or any other information I provide to help work out what's going wrong?

Comment: I don't really know, You get a force close but is it the same stack trace exception ? You can try to comment the whole loop and see what happens. And I ve just seen it, your indexes are bad  "for (int i=1; i<=Mx; i++)" should be  "for (int i=0 ; i< Mx ; i++)" or it will end in ArrayOutOfBoundException. I edit the post

Comment: thanks. I will update the indexes and if k get another force close I'll post the stack trace. thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Ok, hope it help, don't forget to set the question as answered if it does.

Comment: SORTED! Thank you so much for your help, i am missing the first entry (as in mx=1) on the first time through the loop but i am sure I can work that out!  Thanks again for your help